# SharePoint Foundation 2010 local administrator membership

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I've taken on a SharePoint Foundation 2010 site and currently working through making sure things are set as they should be. One of the things I've noticed is that one of the SP users from the backend (sharepoint_db) is present in the Local Administrators group of the server. This in turn makes SPCA complain of this so want to know whether any SP users should be present here?

Cheers
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No SharePoint user should be in the local administrators group. There is really only one exception to this, when patching. During patching your SP_Install or SP_Setup or whatever you call your installation account need to be a local admin during patching. When your done, remove the install account from the local admin group.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was the case but couldn't find any solid documentation online.